# TortoiseSVN log shows that repo has bad times on the versions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using Windows 7 and VisualSVN enterprise on our SVN server which is on our local LAN only.  When I do a TortoiseSVN "show log" on our repo the version numbers are correct but the dates associated with them are scrambled and from various versions.  Doing a fresh checkout of the repo does not fix it but another user does not have this problem and sees the version dates correctly.

- All users now have the same version of tortoise: TortoiseSVN 1.9.7.  The sync was done trying to resolve this problem.  Prior to the symptom one user had TortoiseSVN 1.6.

  I checked the server machine and the timestamps of the files of the repo look OK.

  I checked all the timezones and times of all the users's machines and the server and they are all correct.

  There are some Apache errors thrown in the VisualSVN log but that is all I have is "Apache Error".  Not much to go on and I wouldn't know what to do with Apache anyway.

  "svnadmin verify" on the repo reports that all versions are fine.

  The drive with our repo on it failed about two weeks ago.  We bought a new drive and restored the repo from from an earlier backup (dump).  It has been working fine for about two weeks.

So is my SVN repo corrupt or is there an easy fix to restore the correct times on the versions?

Comment: What does "scrambled" mean? Show an example of something that's broken vs. what you're expecting.

Comment: By "scrambled" I mean that the revision numbers do not increase with the dates.  I checked in revision 1050 on Feb 5 2018, yet later revisions such as 1055 are for earlier dates.  Revision 1055  is shown as the latest revision yet its date is Nov 7 2017.

Comment: Is it possible that someone did a dump/load and merged multiple repositories into one?

Comment: Good question.  I checked with the person who restored the SVN from the dump and he says the old dump became the repo in a new folder and that he didn't merge the old repo with the dump.  That makes sense because the hard drive failed and he didn't have an existing repo to merge to.